# Any update on RINA?

Tags: blockchain

Recursive Interconnect Network Architecture was being discussed for Cardano. Is the networking team or anyone looking into this?

Answer (score 3):

Wayne Jones has written on ***Blockchain Reporter*** the [following](https://blockchainreporter.net/cardano-4-reasons-why-it-is-the-best-example-of-a-perfect-cryptocurrency/):

> To scale its network, Cardano has adopted RINA (Recursive Web Architecture).

So, when **[Basho era](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/3707/ouroboros-which-version/3710#3710)** launches, we'll see RINA's implementation in action.